# Spring + H2DB-Web-Console: "This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not."

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, h2, web-console

My ultimate goal is the use the [h2db-web-console](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database) in my application, as part of my local dev environment.

I'm getting the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
>
> This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet=[/my-h2-console/*], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.
>
> For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.

While this sounds pretty descriptive it drives me crazy, since it appears it doesn't matter which path I use for JakartaWebServlet=[**/my-h2-console/***], since DispatcherServlet=[**/**] simply matches everything. that starts with "/"...which is everything.

> ...please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher)...

Well, those are deprecated with Spring 3.x.x [patchnotes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) so I've tried using the RequestMatcher(this should be automatically be used with 'authorize') instead.

**Security-Config**

```
    @Bean
    @Order(GENERAL_SECURITY_CONFIGURATION_ORDER)
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            ...
            }
            securityMatcher("/**")
            headers { frameOptions { disable() } }
            csrf { ignoringRequestMatchers("/my-h2-console/**") }

            authorizeRequests {
                authorize("/my-h2-console/**", permitAll)
                authorize("/ping", permitAll)
                authorize("/**", denyAll)
            }
        }
        return http.build()
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope> <!-- Should be "test", revert later -->
        </dependency>
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /my-h2-console
      settings:
        trace: false
        web-allow-others: false
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  sql:
    init:
      mode: embedded
      schema-locations: classpath:sql/schema.testdb.local.sql
```

Please keep in mind, I'm new to spring-boot in general, so please be gentle. Any kind of information regarding this topic is kindly appreciated. :)

I tried:

- changing the paths/names of the servlets as stated above
- changed the scope of my H2DB
- Tried different configurations in my Security-Config

=> Only turning off/on

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
```

seems to bring any change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This configuration helped me to resolve H2 issue:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    // My enpdoints start from /v1 so this pattern is ok for me
    private static final String API_URL_PATTERN = "/v1/**";

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain getSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                      HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);

        http.csrf(csrfConfigurer ->
                csrfConfigurer.ignoringRequestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(API_URL_PATTERN),
                        PathRequest.toH2Console()));

        http.headers(headersConfigurer ->
                headersConfigurer.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth
                        .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern(API_URL_PATTERN)).permitAll()
                        //This line is optional in .authenticated() case as .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        //would be applied for H2 path anyway
                        .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toH2Console()).authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

More [info](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13568#issuecomment-1712754300).

Updated code for H2 console to work properly in browser.

Also `PathRequest.toH2Console()` could be used instead of `AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/h2-console/**")`

Comment: Yes, following fixed my issue, thanks;

authorize(PathRequest.toH2Console(), permitAll)

Answer (score 0):

how about try antMatcher?
i don't know kotlin but I hope it helps

```
 authorizeRequests {
            authorize(antMatcher("/my-h2-console/**"), permitAll)
            //...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Denis Korolev this solved it, thank you!

```
 @Bean
    fun securityFilterChainTestEnv(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
                ...
            }

            headers { frameOptions { disable() } }
            csrf { ignoringRequestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")) }

            http.authorizeHttpRequests { httpSecurity ->
                val mvcIntrospector = HandlerMappingIntrospector()
                httpSecurity
"/ping-test")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().denyAll()
            }
        }
        return http.build()
    }
```