# Spring boot 3 security, This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-3, spring-boot-security

Note: What i'm trying to achieve is to know why spring boot asking to specify mvcMatcher or antMatcher.

Spring boot security SecurityFilterChain config not accepting requestMatchers with string value, and showing below exception on startup:

.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'configure' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

below is Bean code:

`

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request ->
                    request.requestMatchers(("/public/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(("/api/v1/admin/**")).hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated());
    return httpSecurity.build();
}
```

`

It worked when I used MvcRequestMatcher but why is failing without it.

Note:
I'm using H2 DB for unit test and DB2 for the application.

Comment: Do you use the H2 console?

Comment: I wrote an answer about this topic some time ago, [here you are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852537/endpoint-spring-security-configuration-returning-the-method-cannot-decide-whet/76865442#76865442), if it will help you and solve the problem don`t forget to upvote it.

Comment: There are several of these Q&A's on Stack Overflow, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77024398/1915448) (specifically for H2 console) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76809698/1915448) as well.

Comment: Anyways, I closed the question as a duplicate of the three earlier mentioned questions. If you believe your question to be different from those three, please edit your question to clarify why you think it's different.

Comment: @g00glen00b Yes i use h2 db for unit test

Comment: @AndreiLisa thank you for your answer but what i'm trying to know is why it's not working without mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern or ant matcher,

Comment: if you read all references that i gave to that answer, you should get that it was an regression.

Comment: It boils down to: if you use multiple servlets, you have to specifically mention which servlet your requestmatcher should be applied to. And since the H2 web console registers its own servlet, you fall within that category. As for the why you should, check the attached CVE in the duplicates.