# Spring + H2DB-Web-Console: "more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have the same problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024398/spring-h2db-web-console-this-method-cannot-decide-whether-these-patterns-are) question. I implemented the code provided in the accepted answer however it only worked when I removed my roles configurations (See code below)

My routes:

```java
    private static final String[] PUBLIC = {"/auth/login", "/auth/register"};

    private static final String USER = "/reserves/**";

    private static final String OWNER_OR_ADMIN = "/houses/**";

    private static final String ADMIN = "/users/**";
```

My SecurityFilter:

```java
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        return http
                .csrf(csrfConfigurer ->
                        csrfConfigurer.ignoringRequestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/**"),
                                 PathRequest.toH2Console()))
                .cors(cors -> cors
                        .configurationSource(req -> {
                            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                            config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
                            config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
                            return config;
                        }))
                .headers(headersConfigurer ->
                        headersConfigurer.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))
                .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/")).authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(PUBLIC).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(USER).hasAnyRole("USER", "OWNER", "ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET ,"/houses/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers(OWNER_OR_ADMIN).hasAnyRole("OWNER", "ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(ADMIN).hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
```

Note that my application need to have this roles configurations for each route.

Working code (removing route roles config):

```java
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        return http
                .csrf(csrfConfigurer ->
                        csrfConfigurer.ignoringRequestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/**"),
                                 PathRequest.toH2Console()))
                .cors(cors -> cors
                        .configurationSource(req -> {
                            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                            config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
                            config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
                            return config;
                        }))
                .headers(headersConfigurer ->
                        headersConfigurer.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))
                .sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/")).permitAll()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
```

The error message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/append/backend/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet=[/h2-console/*], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/]}.
```

Please keep in mind, I'm new to spring-boot in general, this is my first project, so please be nice.

I tried basicly everithing sugested in the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024398/spring-h2db-web-console-this-method-cannot-decide-whether-these-patterns-are) question.